# How can I successfully set up my fans to run on my CR-10 using Marlin?

Tags: marlin, creality-cr-10, skr-mini-e3, print-fan, fans

I have a CR-10 (original version), and I just installed an SKR E3 Mini V3.0 board, with custom Marlin firmware.  Everything else seems to be running properly, but some of my fans won't spin, or won't spin correctly.

The CR-10 has four fans:

1. the parts cooling fan, which has variable speeds and is controlled by the G-code,
2. the heat sink fan, which should either be always on, or should activate when the heat sink registers 50 °C or higher, and
3. a fan inside the control box, near the rear of the case, and
4. a fan inside the control , near the front of the case, by the LCD screen.

The parts cooling fan seems to be operating correctly.  The heat sink fan won't turn on at all.  Inside the case, 3) operates correctly, and 4) spins very slowly and loudly.

I have read that you have to do something to the configuration files to instruct Marlin on which pins correspond to which fans, but any examples I find refer to Ender 3 printers and not to CR-10s.  How do I troubleshoot the fans and/or edit the Marlin configuration files to set up my fans properly?

Comment: A standard CR-10 has a heat sink fan that receives continues power, did you change that yourself? Furthermore, fan 3 and 4 are also continuously powered fans, so if you have used the same power supply, and as such the same voltage, nothing can be different for them. Measure the output of the fans with a multimeter.

Comment: I've figured out some things since my original post.  First, I had some of the connectors plugged into the wrong ports on the new mainboard.  Second, Marlin is set up so that the heat sink fan turns on only when the hot end reaches 50 degrees, and the controller fans turn on only when any of the stepper motors have been engaged, and turns off a short while after they go idle.  Third, fan 4) is dying, so I'll be installing a replacement today.

Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: Great to hear you are troubleshooting! Please make it a (partial) answer so that others may learn from it! Comments are transient and may be removed.